# Access property inside a block objective c

Tags: objective-c, properties, block

```
- (IBAction)saveBtn:(id)sender {
    UIImage* imageToSave = [self imageByCombiningImage:self.backgroundImage.image withImage:self.tempImage.image];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    // Request to save the image to camera roll

    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[imageToSave CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[imageToSave imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        } else {
            CGFloat compression = 0.0;         
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, compression);
            UIImage *compressedImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
            NSMutableString *imageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

            CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
            if (theUUID) {
                [imageName appendString:CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID))];
                CFRelease(theUUID);
            }
            [imageName appendString:@".png"];

            NSLog(@"Image name: %@", imageName);

            //Image Data to web service
            [self uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(compressedImage, 1.0) filename:imageName];

            _savedImageURL = assetURL;
            [library assetForURL:_savedImageURL
                     resultBlock:resultblock
                    failureBlock:failureblock];
    }];
}

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref) {
        UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        //image Property needs to be access here
    }
};
```

I cannot access any property inside this block. Like I have made a UIImage property in the .h file but I cannot accessed that in that result block.

Comment: A lot more information is required. Where is this block defined? What error do you get? Your comment hints at you trying to access an _instance variable_ (that may be generated by a property), is that really what you want. **Please edit your question** and provide more code and details. **Do not post code in comments**, thank you.

Comment: where do you assign the block?

Comment: Block is assign and implemented in the .m file

Comment: Why are you using ALAssetsLibrary, it was deprecated in iOS 8 :)

Comment: Please explain what issue you are having that is preventing you from accessing a property inside the block.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid as-is. Please fix it.

Comment: How do you know you can't access a property in the block? We'd like you to clean up the code please format, and also to see the results.

Comment: Also do you mean by "cannot access" read or write or both?

Comment: Kudos for actually editing your question and not posting code in comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the code you've posted is really the one you're using, then it's defining a variable which references a block. But that variable is *not* part of your class and you thus cannot reference any instance variables.

Instead, the variable is on the "C top-level", outside any class. You might want to turn it into an instance variable, for example like this:

```
@interface MyClass : SomeSuperClass
{
    // Define an instance variable.
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock;
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)someMethod
{
    // Initialize the variable in `init`, `viewDidLoad` or whichever
    // method suits you.
    resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
        if (iref) {
            UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
           //image Property needs to be access here
        }
   };
}

@end
```

You could also use a property instead.

Comment: But you are not using `self` or any instance variables here either. And if you did, it would create a retain cycle.

Comment: @newacct: You do know the trick of creating a weak reference to `self` before the block and making it strong inside the block to break the retain cycle?

Answer (score -3):

Next solution is you can create block property from whole controller like this:

```
__block MyViewController *blocksafeSelf = self;
```

and inside block you can use this property to access:

```
blocksafeSelf.myProperty;
```

or call method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
      [blocksafeSelf processNewMessage:text]  
});
```

Comment: `__block` is only for if the variable will be assigned to. `self` is not assigned to anywhere here.